# Does Acer use a BIOS whitelist on my Acer Aspire One ZG5?

Tags: wireless-networking, upgrade, acer-aspire-one

I have a Acer netbook sitting around, and I'm going to upgrade the card, however, I don't know if Acer uses a whitelist. **Does Acer use a whitelist? If so, how can I tell if my WiFi card I'm going to install is on it?**

Comment: You should include the model ID of the wireless card in the post in case somebody can confirm it.

Comment: @parashep it is http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B007QXLIWI/ref=redir_mdp_mobile/183-2705949-5988751?ref_=cm_cd_ql_qh_dp_t

Comment: That looks like it's a half-sized mini PCIe card. The Aspire One uses a full-sized mini PCIe card, that may be a bigger issue than compatibility with the BIOS.

Comment: @parashep No, there are half to full adapters that you can buy for $3: http://compare.ebay.com/like/180646686696?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar

Comment: Okay. Just making sure you knew about that. I haven't been able to find any published data about a whitelist for the ZG5, though.

Comment: @parashep Thanks for looking. I couldn't find one for *any* Acer model, but no one explicitly said that there was or wasn't one. I guess that it would be wider known if there was one, and Acer would post it. If I do try it, I'll post if it works.